# Taблица treeview в tkinker вылазит за границы окна

Tags: python, tkinter, gui, treeview, таблицы

Есть небольшой интерфейс на tkinker. в нем три кнопки и таблица из 50 столбцов. При запуске возникает две проблемы:

1. Таблица вылезает за рамки окна. Не получается это поправить, ни при методе `pack()`, ни при методе `grid()`.
2. Не получается добавить к таблице прокрутку, она просто не появляется при таком коде:

```
scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(window,orient=HORIZONTAL,command=table.xview)
table.configure(xscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.pack()
```

Код программы, который есть на данный момент:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
window = Tk()
window.config(bg='#C9C5C5')  
window.title("Добро пожаловать в приложение PythonRu")  
window.geometry('1600x900')


frame_buttons = Frame(window)
frame_buttons.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)

frame_table = Frame(window)
frame_table.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=BOTH)


start = Button(frame_buttons, text="Старт", width=13, height=2, bg='#B5B2B2', command=lambda: print_reg_values(registers_list, tree))
start.pack(side=TOP)  
stop = Button(frame_buttons, text="Стоп", width=13, height=2, bg='#B5B2B2', command=stop_func)
stop.pack(side=TOP)    
downdload_file = Button(frame_buttons, text="Загрузить в файл", width=13, height=2, bg='#B5B2B2', command=lambda: download(registers_list))  
downdload_file.pack(side=TOP)


columns_list = ['Время']
for i in range(1, 51):
    columns_list.append(i)
columns = tuple(columns_list)
table = ttk.Treeview(frame_table, columns=columns, show="headings")
table.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
table.heading("Время", text="Время")
table.column('Время', stretch=NO, width=50)
for i in range(1, 51):
    table.heading(i, text=i)
    table.column(i, stretch=NO, width=35, anchor=CENTER)

scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(window,orient=HORIZONTAL,command=table.xview)
table.configure(xscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Вот так выглядит окно с таблицей на данный момент:
[image: Скрин окна]

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под "Таблица вылезает за рамки окна"? На скриншоте все в пределах окна.

Comment: @insolor, я подразумеваю, что часть таблицы не помещается в окно (с 41 по 50 столбцы), при этом ее никак не промотать и не посмотреть. Хотелось бы, чтобы таблица помещалась в окно вне зависимости  от количества и ширины столбцов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скроллбар создавайте в том же фрейме, что и таблицу (`frame_table`), при размещении указывайте заполнение по горизонтали (`fill=X`):

```
scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(frame_table,orient=HORIZONTAL,command=table.xview)
scrollbar.pack(fill=X)
table.configure(xscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
```

[image: Скриншот]

Чтобы была прокрутка по вертикали и горизонтали, удобнее использовать `grid` вместо `pack` (иначе или горизонтальный или вертикальный сколлбар будет выходить за размеры таблицы).

Изменения:

```
table = ttk.Treeview(frame_table, columns=columns, show="headings")
table.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=NSEW)

...

xscrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(frame_table,orient=HORIZONTAL,command=table.xview)
xscrollbar.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=EW)
table.configure(xscrollcommand=xscrollbar.set)

yscrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(frame_table,orient=VERTICAL,command=table.yview)
yscrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=NS)
table.configure(yscrollcommand=yscrollbar.set)

frame_table.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame_table.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

[image: Скриншот с горизонтальной и вертикальной прокруткой]

Comment: Спасибо, решение помогло. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем суть вот этих двух строк:
`frame_table.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)`
`frame_table.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)`

Comment: Это добавление нулевой колонке и нулевой строке (где находится таблица) дополнительного "веса", из-за чего эти колонка и строка максимально возможно расширяются, и из-за этого строки и колонки со скроллбарами будут занимать наоборот минимальное место (по умолчанию "вес" равен нулю). Попробуйте убрать эти строки и сравнить.